# I'm trying to save array of strings to a txt file

Tags: c#

I'm designing a program to save food recipes. The problem is when I save the ingredients of a new recipe it deletes the ingredients of the old recipe. I want both of them to be saved. Here's the code I use:

```
Console.WriteLine("Enter the path where your files will be saved: ");
                            
string fileName = Console.ReadLine();
                            
Console.WriteLine("Please enter the main ingrediant for your recipe: ");
                            
string Main = Console.ReadLine();

Console.WriteLine("Please enter how many ingrediants in your recipe: ");
int Ingrediants = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

string[] a = new string[Ingrediants];

Recpies recipe1 = new Recpies(Main, Ingrediants);
recipe1.Ingrediants = new List<string[]>();
recipe1.TheMainIngrediant = Main;

Console.WriteLine("Please enter your ingrediants: ");
for (int i = 0; i < Ingrediants; i++)
{
        a[i] = Console.ReadLine();
        
}
using (var file = System.IO.File.OpenText(fileName))
{
    string line;
    while ((line = file.ReadLine()?.Trim()) != null)
    {
        // skip empty lines 
        if (line == string.Empty)
        {
            recipe1.Ingrediants.Add(a);
            recipe1.Saving(fileName, Ingrediants, a);
        }
        else
        {
            continue;   
        }
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Please, have a look at `File.AppendAllText(...)` and `File.AppendAllLines(...)`

Comment: I think you mean `if (line != string.Empty)` based on the comment `// skip empty lines`

Comment: It would be far simpler to read everything in then save everything else out once. It seems like this is what you want to do and are using ```(line == string.Empty)``` to tell when you're at the end of the file - but that's not guaranteed since you could easily have an empty line anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible way to achieve what you want is to use a combination between `StreamWriter` and `File.AppendText`, this is not going to overwrite the `text` you already save on that file instead of that is going to append the info at the end of the file (this example might be helpful: [Append Text](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.appendtext?view=net-5.0)). Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Just add `true` as second parameter

```
TextWriter tsw = new StreamWriter(fileName, true);
```